# How to clone and customize control

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, clone

I might be in that situation: in a stack panel I want to add a separator then button then separator then button and so on...
The separator is always the same and so are the button except for some fields.
I can't use the same separator since a control can be only child of another control. So I have to define sep1 button1 sep2 button2 sep3 button3....

What I'd like is something like (pseudocode):

> Sepator sep = new Separator();
>
> Button but = new Button();
>
> StackPanel stp = new StackPanel();
>
> stp.Add(new sepator().Clone(sep));
>
> stp.Add(new sepator().Clone(Button{ Content = "BT1"}));
>
> stp.Add(new sepator().Clone(sep));
>
> stp.Add(new sepator().Clone(Button{ Content = "BT2"}));
>
> ...

The only way to clone a control I've found googling is:

```
MyControl copy = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(controlInstance)) as MyControl;
```

MyControl copy = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(controlInstance)) as MyControl;

but I don't like it. Why have I got to go to Xaml to clone a control? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You don't have to clone anything. Just create appropriate default Styles for Separator and Button.

Comment: Why do you need to clone objects instead of simply create a new instance of the object?

Comment: To define buttons and sepators once only and then reuse all the settings

Comment: That's what Styles were invented for.

Comment: Fine thanks! Just for sake of completeness would you  post a sample code as answer? thank you

Comment: How would I possible do that when you haven't told us anything about the properties you want to set? If you don't know how to write a default Style, just add a Style to your Window's Resources, set its TargetType, and omit the `x:Key`.

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer it was just a way to close this question with a standard code to help others. If you don't want it's fine for me, I already have set your comment as useful.